# Why do executables have different behavior that the repl behavior?

Tags: common-lisp, executable, sbcl

### My Setup

I develop common lisp with emacs + slime. My machine is a mac pro M1. And, I use the kitty terminal emulator.

### The Situation

When I run my app (see code at the end) in the repl, it works fine.

When I create and run the executable, it's as if the order of the program is different.

For example, I have 5 questions which asks for user input...

```lisp
(defpackage custom-sender
  ;; import the exactly the symbols I need from a package
  (:import-from :cl-json :encode-json-to-string)
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :main))

(in-package custom-sender)

(defun main()
  (asking-questions))


(defun asking-questions ()
  (let ((firstname (prompt-read "What is the firstname of the contact?"))
        (email (prompt-read "What is their email?"))
        (job (prompt-read "What is the job?"))
        (first-line (prompt-read "what is the first line of their address?"))
        (sending-account (prompt-read "Which email account do you want to send from? (e2, e3 etc)")))

    (status-update "some text ~a" email);; <-- this function is executed BEFORE the "sending-account" question is asked

... ) ;;<-- end of let block

  )
```

```
(defun status-update (message value)
  (format *query-io* (concatenate 'string message "~C~C") value  #\linefeed #\linefeed)
  (force-output *query-io*))

(defun prompt-read (question)
  (format *query-io* "~a:  " question)
  (read-line *query-io*)
  (force-output *query-io*))
```

### The Problem

When running the executable, there are two issues:

1. The first function `(status-update...)` is executed before the final prompt read. In the terminal, the question comes up but immediately exits. So I cannot enter anything.
2. Also... `(status-update...)` gets the value of `email` which is `NIL`. Even though I entered a value inside the terminal.

This entire process runs perfectly in the repl.

Note - I am building the executable with the ASD MAKE process.

Comment: where is `asking-questions` invoked?  please provide a minimal complete example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hint: when you post the code you need to format it better. People expect that Lisp code is perfectly indented, because the editor usually does it. One problem here is that you use tabs for indentation. That causes in Stackoverflow problems. Usually it is better to use space characters for indentation. Best to configure the editor use space for indentation, too.

Comment: What does the source for the function PROMPT-READ look like?

Comment: Updated code blocks with other functions used within `asking questions`

Comment: Okay, I will make sure my emacs is reconfigured with spaces for my next question. I am curious, which line in the above codeblock is not indented properly? And what is the standard number of spaces expected for CL?

Comment: Just use SLIME&GNU Emacs to indent the code. Don't do it manually.

Comment: In PROMPT-READ you are reading a line, without forcing pending output first. Common Lisp does allow output to be buffered underneath. Depending where the output is done, it may be buffered.

Comment: regarding indenting. My indents are done with `tab` which auto indents them.

Comment: Prompt read was the correct answer. Please add it as an answer to I can mark it as correct :) (thanks again!)

Comment: tip: see `uiop:format!`, it flushes output streams before and after the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun prompt-read (question)
  (format *query-io* "~a:  " question)
  (read-line *query-io*)
  (force-output *query-io*))
```

change it to something like this:

```
(defun prompt-read (question)
  (format *query-io* "~a:  " question)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*)
  (force-output *query-io*))
```

Otherwise the prompt may not be visible when the function is waiting for input..., due to a buffering output stream.

Streams may or may not buffer output. For portable programs you'd need to add operations to clear or force output.